# Can't run pear command after installation on Windows

Tags: php, windows-xp, installation, pear

I'm using **XAMPP** on my **WINDOWS/XP** local machine. Here are my installation steps:

- Running **xampp\php\go-pear.bat**
- I choose, "**SYSTEM WIDE**" by entering "system"
- Continued with **"default" individual locations** (Pressing "Enter")
- Then, double clicked "**PEAR_ENV.reg**"

After install, while i call "pear" from Command Prompt, it is showing:

```
'pear' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Here are my "System Environment Variables" and i got all files (and "PEAR" folder) correctly:

- PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR = C:\Program Files\xampp\php
- PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR = C:\Program Files\xampp\php\data
- PHP_PEAR_DOC_DIR = C:\Program Files\xampp\php\docs
- PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR = C:\Program Files\xampp\php\pear
- PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN = C:\Program Files\xampp\php.\php.exe
- PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR = C:\Program Files\xampp\php
- PHP_PEAR_TEST_DIR = C:\Program Files\xampp\php\tests

**What did i do wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your `PATH` environment variable to include the location of the `pear` command.  Here is an article on how to do this:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: No problem!  Glad to be of help.